# Customizing modal Login Form data-dojo-attach-point as id

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dom-events

I am trying to customize a modal login form.

How can I apply `data-dojo-attach-point` id to `document.getElementById('id');` as below in order to grab the button id?

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" 
        data-dojo-attach-event="onClick:toggleEditing" 
        data-dojo-props="label:'${i18n.labels.startEditing}','class':'success'" 
        data-dojo-attach-point="toggleBTN">
    </button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: instead of document.getElementById('id01') see if you can use document.getElementsByName('id01')[0].elements. you need have name attribute in your html